# Hide youtube video after playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube

I have a webpage, and I made a video for it. With HTML5 formats (webm,ogg,mp4) works only the Chrome correctly. When the video is finishing, I can hide the video with JavaScript. I thought I can make with youtube player, (autoplay, hide controls etc) but i can't hide it, when it is finished. I found the "`onStateChange` function but I can't use it. Any ideas?

```
<iframe width="840" height="630" src="URLrel=0&showinfo=0;&autoplay=1;controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `YouTube Iframe Player API` to check (1) that the video has ended (`YT.PlayerState.ENDED`) when `onPlayerStateChange` is invoked, and (2) remove/hide the DOM element that contains the video, i.e. the iframe.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    // check if video ended and remove player
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      console.log($('#player').remove());
      done = true;
    }
  }
```

You have a fully working solution in here:  http://jsfiddle.net/jibietr/ua57A/1/

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be to use innerHTML to overwrite the iframe when the user closes the video with an onclick event. If the iframe is wrapped inside a  with id = "iframeDiv", you can call the following function onclick of the close video button:

```
function hideIframe() {
    document.getElementById("iframeDiv").innerHTML = '';
}
```

The iframe would reappear when the user opens the video:

```
function showIframe() {
    document.getElementById("iframeDiv").innerHTML = '<iframe width="840" height="630" src="URLrel=0&showinfo=0;&autoplay=1;controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}
```